# Write cell data to a HTML table using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm having trouble putting together the final function displayLetter(a, b, c, d,  e,f, g) below and writing to a table in innerHTML with the array element and variables in variableTest(). I know I need to use .length and to determine how many cells I need. W3C only gets me so far. Thanks for the help!

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>
     </title>
     <script>
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1>TEST THIS SCRIPT</h1>
     <table border="1">
      <tr>
       <th>A</th>
       <th>B</th>
       <th>C</th>
       <th>D</th>
       <th>E</th>
       <th>F</th>
       <th>G</th>
      </tr>
     <a href="add data" id="reload">Add Employee</a>
   </body>
 <html>
```

MY JS:

```
 function addData()
 {
    var testarray = new Array();
    testarray[0] = window.prompt("Enter a letter", "z");
    variableTest(x, y);
    displaySalary(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
 }


 function variableTest(x, y)
 {
    a=1;
    b=2;
    c=3;
    d=4;
    e=5;
 }


 displayLetter(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
 {
    // Code to write the variables to the table 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do but few things pop out. I'd suggest you declare `var testarray = new Array();` outside of any function. Then in
`function addData()

{

testarray.push (window.prompt("Enter a letter"));

}`

What is variableTest() supposed to do?

When calling addDate is it supposed to add the prompted text into a cell in that table?